# What Does It mean to 'Solve the System' when given a two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was hoping someone could explain what exactly the following question is asking:

> Find for which value $\ k _0 $ of $k$ is the following matrix invertible
>
> A =  $(\begin{matrix} 1 & k \\ 3 & 2 \end{matrix})$
>
> Afterwards solve the system $A( \begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}) = (\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}) $ for $k \ne k_0$.

I understand the first part, I found that A is invertible when $k \ne$ $ -3 \above 1pt 2 $

But I dont understand what the second part of the problem wants me to do. Am i supposed to multiply A by the matrix $(\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix})$ and then put it into an augmented matrix? I'm sorry if this seems like a basic question, but I am just really confused on how to answer this.

If someone could give be a push in the right direction I would really appreciate it. I just ask that you don't give me the answer. I am hoping to try and solve the rest by myself once I know what I need to do.

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! If $A$ is invertible, the system has only the trivial solution.

Comment: you have to solve this System $$x+yk=0$$ and $$3x+2y=0$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Did you get that system simply by multiplying A with $(\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix})$ ?

Comment: yes you must multiply $A$ with $$\binom {x}{y}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&k\\3&2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
means:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x+ky\\3x+2y
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and this is equivalent to the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
x+ky=0\\
3x+2y=0
\end{cases}
$$

can you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: your matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if $k \neq \frac{2}{3}$ (perhaps you have made a computational mistake).

The second question asks you to solve the system $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$, where $\vec{x} = (x,y)^t$ and $\vec{0} = (0,0)^t$ where you have to fill in $k = \frac{2}{3}$. Since this makes the matrix $A$ singular (i.e. non-invertible), you should find infinitely many solutions. (Note that you can fill in $k$, so that you can write down your solutions).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You were right about the computational error. Though, I'm a bit confused why i would fill in k = $2 \above 1pt 3 $ because the question asks ' for $k \ne k_0$'

Comment: No problem. The first question shows that $A$ is invertible for every $k_0 \neq \frac{2}{3}$, so $A$ is invertible for every $k_0 \in ]-\infty, \frac{2}{3}[ \cup ]\frac{2}{3}, + \infty[$. The second question asks you to compute the solutions to the system for every $k \neq k_0$, hence only for $k = \frac{2}{3}$.